# how to evaluate if a project qualifies for or can be retrofitted with JBPM6

Tags: jboss, jbpm

I had used JBPM 3.2 few years back as workflow engine. Now being part of a team were they had recently started a project, i need to evaluate if it can be improved/benefited by retrofitting JBPM 6 on it.
I am new to JBPM 6 so i read and researched to find road map for the list of changes,
http://www.jboss.org/jbpm/roadmap

whats new,
http://www.slideshare.net/krisverlaenen/2013-0611-whats-new-in-j-bpm6

did installation, demo and examples using,
http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0/userguide/jBPMEclipseJBPM.html

however i am still coming up to speed in terms of what JBPM was and what it has become in these years and its capabilities. It would be helpful if someone can guide me in terms of what all things in a project scope make is qualify for JBPM 6.

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of reasons / advantages to using business processes (in general):

- dynamic and flexible: extracting business logic in business process
  allows you to evolve it or make it more flexible
- higher-level: business analysts and end users could (possibly) understand and/or author business processes
- monitoring and management: get an overview of all (current and historic) work
- long-running and/or human tasks: some features are sometimes difficult to code but easier to express using specific business process constructs
- performance: high throughput and scalability
- tooling: a lot of out-of-the-box features and tools you can use

[note you definitely don't need to check all of these]

There's more, but you should make sure your benefits outweigh your initial learning curve / added complexity.